# interesting characters in URL in joomla

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

i have a URL that looks like this

......index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=8&Itemid=34

i know that i can view the source of the file just by view source from the browser, but since i have FTP permission for the site, i would like to be able to edit the file.

but i dont know which file to edit!

how do i find out which file is this link going to so that i can access it through ftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be here:

```
 Root Joomla Folder -> Components -> com_jumi
```

Now inside the com_jumi folder, it depends which file you want to edit, for example there you will find the file for current pages looks (View), a file with database queries (Model) and a main logic file called controller. You have to decide which file you want to edit.

Note: inside the com_jumi folder, the files can be inside other folders too, you will have to find out which file you want to edit.

Comment: actually this one http://yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=8&Itemid=34